# Regex Variables (like in preg_replace)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to make a WebSocket chat with NodeJS, and at this moment I'm trying to make a basic regex replace function. I'm trying to do the following things:

1. Replace `**randomTxt**` with `<b>randomTxt\</b>`
2. Replace `https://link.com/` with `<a href="https://link.com">https://link.com/</a>`

In PHP, I could just do

```
$message = preg_replace('#\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}#', '<b>$1</b>', $message);
$message = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $message);
```

But in NodeJS, it seems that I cant use Regex variables like "$1". (tried new RegExp, and just replace(//), doesn't work. This is what I tried below.

```
var linkReg = new RegExp("#\\*{2}(.*?)\\*{2}#", 'g');
str = str.replace(linkReg, "<b>$1</b>");

return str;
```

Is there an equivalent of preg_replace, or is there another way I can use Regex variables?

Comment: Can you show us your JavaScript regex code?

Comment: @JosanIracheta added my attempt

Comment: your regexp as it stands looks for strings that start and end with `#` ... but the example string does not start or end with `#` ... is `#` the delimeter in PHP - you just need `str.replace(/\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/g, "<b>$1</b>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var text = 'bla bla **randomTxt** bla bla **randomTxt** bla bla'
var patt = /\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/g;
var new_text = text.replace(patt, '<b>$1</b>')
console.log(new_text)
```

```js
var text = 'bla bla https://link.com/ bla bla https://link.com/ bla bla'
var patt = /(https?:\/{2}[^/]+\/)/g;
var new_text = text.replace(patt, '<a href=$1>$1</a>')
console.log(new_text)
```